# Необходимо ли указывать знаки препинания перед ссылкой на электронные ресурсы, такие как двоеточие или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Необходимо ли указывать знаки препинания перед ссылкой на электронные ресурсы в статье, такие как двоеточие или тире?
Примеры:
В актуальной версии Описание XSD https://, а также действующие «паспорта процессов»: https://. ПП РФ 0000 - https://

Comment: [ГОСТ Р 7.0.5-2008 «Библиографическая ссылка. Общие требования и правила составления»](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82_%D1%80_7_0_5_2008_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

Comment: В смысле? Нужны ли двоеточия при вводе ссылки? Да, ещё как нужны, без них ссылка не откроется.